# Why do I use 'end)' instead of just end |?

Tags: lua

```
    draw.RoundedBox(0,0,0,100,100,Color(120,255,120))
end)
```

I'm watching tutorials for learning Lua, more specifically Lua for the Garry's Mod engine. During the tutorial, I noticed using just 'end' didn't work. I had to use 'end)' with a ')'.

Why do I have to place a ')' at the end of end in this code?

Comment: you did not post the complete code as claimed in the comment below. you missed an entire line from the youtube video you linked https://youtu.be/UK-9ZRpBkLs?t=446 please be more careful.

Answer (score 2):

Some functions take other functions as parameters.

When you see a function called like this:
`hello(param, function(a) print(a) end)`

(Sorry, poor example. This function doesn't really do anything) The function on the inside is called internally from the source of the `hello` function.

The `end` is the end of the inside function, and the `)` is the end of the parameter list for the first function.

---

So here we have a function `hook.Add()` being called:

```
hook.Add("HUDPaint", "DrawMyHud", function()
     draw.RoundedBox(0,0,0,100,100,Color(120,255,120))
end)
```

and from the [GMOD wiki](https://wiki.facepunch.com/gmod/hook.Add):

```
hook.Add( string eventName, any identifier, function func )
--Add a hook to be called upon the given event occurring.
```

Although we're *calling* a function, what the function *is doing* is creating a special connection in the code called a hook. On the event "HUDPaint", the GMOD client will call the function provided.

Another way to write this function that might make the meaning of `end)` more clear is by making each parameter it's own line:

```
hook.Add(
     "HUDPaint", 
     "DrawMyHud", 
      function() draw.RoundedBox(0,0,0,100,100,Color(120,255,120)) end --end of function declaration
) --end of hook.Add function call
```

Comment: If you post the entire function you got your code snippet from I could try and break it down in clearer language.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UK-9ZRpBkLs at 7:27

What I posted is the entire code, but this area in the tutorial video is the context of it.

Comment: Alright I've just added more text to the answer that I hope will be more clear.